# C++Builder XE3 needs to be restarted after each run in the debugger or app crashes on next run

Tags: crash, c++builder, access-violation, c++builder-xe2, c++builder-xe

This is kind of weird, and I only seem to be seeing this on Windows 7 (when I build the app in windows 8 this does not seem to be happening). I see this with C++Builder XE through XE3. I will compile an app (statically linking the packages and the rtl), and then run it from the debugger. If I then make a change to the code and try to recompile and run the app, the compile appears to go ok, but the app crashes when it tries to start. If I close C++Builder and reopen it, then force it to rebuild either by doing a rebuild all, or making a minor change it compiles and runs fine. This is the case every time. I have tried in the past to switch to dynamically linking the rtl and that "appeared" to make the problem go away but I am not sure if that is a solid assumption. Has anyone seen this behaviour, and does anyone know how to resolve it. It is getting tiresome to have to restart the IDE all the time.

**Edit:**
The crash happens before any of my code. Here is the call stack:

```
007d17b3; __delayLoadHelper2
007d7efa; __imageBase
007d308b; __wstartup
```

btw: there are no delay load dlls in this project.

Comment: This still happens in XE7. This behaviour just suddenly started out of the blue for a project that was running fine for over a year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Embarcadero Forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=559403), Try disabling "Incremental Linking".

Comment: yes, that made the problem go away. Thank you for finding that. Of course, this is really gonna suck on the larger projects during build time, but it is better than nothing I guess. When I think on it, restarting builder seemed to make it do a full link too. At least the link would take a really long time compared to when I just make a minor change, so incremental linking is busted. I hope they fix it soon. It's been like this since XE if not earlier.